# How to use DISTINCT command in SQL

Tags: mysql

Below shows my data table name called "company"

[image]

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    name, COUNT(DISTINCT num) AS count
FROM 
    company
WHERE 
    (num LIKE '51%' OR num LIKE '65%' OR num LIKE '81%')
GROUP BY 
    name
```

After run this query it shows below result

[image]

But I need below result. Please help me to solve my problem. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the like operator for the num column, is it a varchar?

Comment: So you want to count the distincts numbers with only 2 first digits ?

Comment: yes it is in varchar

Comment: yes only with  first 2 digits

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to have the distinct on the first 2 characters of the column.

You can use [*the function LEFT()*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) for this:

**Query**

```
SELECT name , COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(num, 2)) AS count
FROM new_table
WHERE ( num LIKE '51%' OR num LIKE '65%' OR num LIKE '81%')
GROUP BY name
```